# IAM permission for s3:PutBucketInventoryConfiguration

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to run the boto3 put_bucket_inventory_configuration s3 command, but I am getting an access denied error:
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutBucketInventoryConfiguration operation: Access Denied

I am not sure what I need to add to my IAM permissions to get access, as s3:PutBucketInventoryConfiguration doesn't exist and s3:PutObject isn't giving me access either. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s3:PutInventoryConfiguration` is what you are looking for.

Comment: This is pretty confusing.  The documentation shows both `s3:PutBucketInventoryConfiguration` and `s3:PutInventoryConfiguration`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketInventoryConfiguration.html.  This is only one example, there are other places as well where the difference show up.

Comment: @MichaelHogenson [PutBucketInventoryConfiguration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutBucketInventoryConfiguration.html) is the API action. [`s3:PutInventoryConfiguration`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) is the IAM policy action.